# Web speech API stops listening after some time passes without input

Tags: google-chrome, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm using the web speech API but once a bit of time passes by (a minute or 2) without any vocal input, it stops listening entirely. I know this because I have it log its parsed text to the console, however, it stops doing this when I do not talk for a minute or two.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The top answer serves to fix this specific question, but in the latest version of Chrome the user will have to allow recording every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can listen to the `end` event and then restart the recognition on the `SpeechRecognition` object.

You should use a boolean flag for deciding (in the `onend` event handler), when to restart the recognition (and when not to restart).

You could use the other recognition-related events for this.

E.g. Chrome triggers the following event handlers when recognition is started:

```
1. onstart
2. onaudiostart

   (only if sound / speech is detected)
3. onsoundstart
4. onspeechstart
```

If no sound speech is detected, only the first 2 will be triggered, and then, after some timeout, the corresponding `end` events (in reverse order).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for this could probably be to listen for the end event and restart the recognition

```
recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start);
```

Comment: I think it is safer to have `recognition.addEventListener('end', () => recognition.start())`; in order to keep `this` context of `.start` method.

Answer (score 1):

`recognition.addEventListener('end', () => recognition.start())` works but Chrome browser seems to obstrruct the continuity by generating a **pop-up** to *Allow* or *Block* the microphone every 5-7 seconds.